# Page Objects (Multi-Level) and Module.Exports / Require with Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

Say the structure is similar to this.

```
|- HomepageTest.js
  |_ pageobject
    |- HomePage.js
      |_modules
        |-Navigation.js
```

If navigation.js is similar to this

```
var LeftNav = function() {
    this.button = element(by.id('someelement');
    this.function = function() {
    browser.button.click();
}
module.exports = new LeftNav();
```

On HomePage.js I'm calling

```
var nav = require("../../modules/navigation");
```

and have the same type of export

```
module.exports = new HomePageObject();
```

On HomepageTest.js I call

```
var homePage = require("../../pageObject/homepage");
```

And I tried to call functions or elements on Navigation by calling

```
homePage.nav.function();
```

and it's not working. I assume it's because i'm doing something wrong in the export but i'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you assign the navigation to `this`? For example: in HomePage.js do `this.nav = require("../../modules/navigation");` inside the constructor.

Comment: Hey Andres, I just tried this and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AndresD I've tried this and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think is not a very good idea calling your stuff `function` plus after the line `this.function = function() {` you seem to be missing the ending `)};`